# How many ways to this methos?

Tags: combinatorics

For black and white case of $m\times n$, only walk diagonally bottom  lower 
left  or lower  right, can walk from the first to the last line,

Question: How many  ways ?

Thank you

Hello,everyone,this problem is from chinese :Hello, I don't translation English too:求m*n 的黑白格中，只走对角线左下或右下， 能从第一行走到最后一行， 方法有几种
[image]

Comment: Can you draw a diagram to illustrate your question?

Comment: Your question is not so clear. I guess you should reformulate it.

Comment: Hello,are you know chinese ? I don't translation English too:求m*n 的黑白格中，只走对角线左下或右下， 能从第一行走到最后一行， 方法有几种

Comment: We can walk left? walk right? walk down? walk up? @chinamath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably closer to the translation of the question. I would post it as a comment but it seems like I'm unable to.

"For a black and white grid of m×n in size, if you are allowed to walk along the bottom-left of the diagonal or the bottom-right of the diagonal, how many ways are there to walk from the first row to the last?"

Your question is badly defined. Please clarify how exactly are you walking.

问题不明确，请说明可以怎么走。

Comment: 意思是：只要是走对角线下面都满足

Comment: 还是不清楚。在小方块上走？上下左右都能走？不可以往回走吧？对角线要是紧挨方块的角算不算？

The previous comment: "As long as you walk underneath the diagonal."

Are walking in the small squares? Are you allowed to walk in all cardinal directions (up, down, left, right)? Are you forbidden from backtracking? Does it count if the diagonal touches the corner of a square?